# Assign new record types to existing objects in Salesforce

Tags: administration, record-type

Is there a way to assign Workflow Rules, Field Updates and process builders ect in bulk to the new record types I will create in Salesforce or do I have to go on each one and do it manually?

**EDIT:** There are none currently and want to add some - I know that new records will have that record type in but not the existing ones...

**EDIT 2:** There will be a merge of 2 SF instances and I want my Workflow Rules, Process builders and Field updates to execute only if the records have my new record type. E.g. if I create an account in my current system and have a workflow that modifies the account, once in the merged system with the other existing data my workflow will only trigger if the account is of my record type - if it hasn't got that record type to it, it should not fire!

I cannot seem to find anything online that explains how to do this in bulk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

Best way to do this, is to export the data through dataloader and update new recordtypeId in the .csv and finally upload the .csv.

**Approach 2**

You can define workflow or process builder's process to update the recordtype.

Since, workflow or process are executed based on create/update action, which you need to perform writing a script and execute the script from Developer Console.

**Approach 3**

You can write a script which will query records in bulk and update the recordtype there without any workflow or process.

**Update based on comments**

You can define workflow rule or process's rule criteria considering recordtype name.

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2. Is there a way to do it with record type names instead than ID?  I just want to know how to make those objects trigger in the new system if assigned to my new record type as the IDs might change during the merge

Comment: your use case can be achievable through use of process builder where it takes recordtype name instead of id.

Comment: Can you give an example on how this would work on Workflows Rules?

Comment: Yes, in the workflow rule criteria you can specify recordtype name